# Не могу установить пакет в Bio-Linux 14.04 + получить доступ к файловой директории для создания конфигурационных файлов

Tags: linux, package

Простая задача, установка, с которой, не могу разобраться, прежде я уже устанавливал, но скорее всего неправильно. Существует пакет RepeatMasker-open-4-0-7.tar.gz, инструкция к установке которой лежит на http://www.repeatmasker.org/RMDownload.html Скачал архив, сделал все по инструкции: 
cp RepeatMasker-open-4-#-#.tar.gz /usr/local – за исключением этого самого «/usr/local», я по всей видимости устанавливаю неправильно, вот как делаю: создаю раздел собственноручно в домашней директории, типа «aset» (мое имя) или «home». 
cd /usr/local
gunzip RepeatMasker-open-4-#-#.tar.gz
tar xvf RepeatMasker-open-4-#-#.tar
После этих команд у меня распакованная папочка лежит, но ничего не происходит, пробовал команды типа «make install» и много-много других, ничего не работает. Полагаю, у меня нет каких-то конфигурационных файлов или скриптов для этих команд, которые, в свою очередь, нужно положить в корневую папку системную, к которой у меня нет никакой доступа. Сможете помочь с этим? 
Я уже так устанавливал пакеты, все хорошо работало + у меня нет доступа к корневому файловому каталогу, в котором системные папки типа (bin, boot, cdrom, dev, etc, home, lib, lib64, lost+found, medai, mnt, proc, root, run, sbin, srv, sys, tmp, usr, var), элементарно не могу даже файл создать в этих разделах, как написано в инструкциях для конфигурационных файлов. Когда в терминале перехожу на в root-режим ничего не меняется, наверное, как в Windows, необходимо предоставить права администратора учетной записи или что-то такое.

Comment: А через sudo пробовал сделать эти самые `cp`? А лучше `sudo -i`, а потом уже по инструкции с сайта. Только это всё небезопасно и я бы сначала отработал на вируталке.

Comment: зачем такие сложности и гадости («скачать бесплатно без эсэмэс и регистрации»), если [пакет есть в репозитории](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=repeatmasker&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) дистрибутива *debian gnu/linux*?